# Separating fields in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table

I would like to separate fields in the attribute console in QGIS. I know it's possible through the field manager, but does anyone know which formula I should use the get the results I want?

The first picture is how it now is, the second one is how I would like it to be.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess the resulting `Name` is allways == "mb"? And the resulting `test 1` is allways the same three-digit substring of the second part of the originating `Name`? If I guess wrong, could you tell us a bit more about the rules that apply to achieve your results?

Comment: attribute console = attribute table? field manager = field calculator?

Comment: is `test 1` of type string or integer?

Answer (score 4):

Considering my above assumptions I would do as follows. **Note** that you can only create/modify one filed at once using field calculator.

First step: Create `test 1` as a substring of original `Name`. Since it is obviously possible that more than one whitespace separate the two parts I use `right` here:

[image]

If `test 1` should be integer, set *Output field type* accordingly and put a `to_int(...)` around your expression.

Second step: Create `Name 1` as a left string of length 2 of original `Name`. I recommend not to modify your source data in case of errors. I too recommend virtual fields since they update on the fly in case of data changes:

[image]

**Note** the preview in the bottom left corner of the field calculator.

And I would like to recommend further reading about the field calculator: https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator

Comment: Thank you for your reaction, although this way did allow me to delete certain parts of the characters I did not want, it still wasn't exactly what I was looking for. I posted another comment with the solution that I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The thing I was looking for that allows me to do what I want is:

```
regexp_substr("name",‘(?<=MBT00L\\s)\\d+(?=00)'))
```

this creates a second column with the info I want. all while doing it in one step.